# Building a cache with TTL feature in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can one implement a cache supporting timeouts `(TTL)` values in JavaScript using Lodash?

`_.memorize` doesn't have a `TTL` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `memoize()` for this. It defeats the purpose of memoization, which is to cache the results of a computation that *never change*, for a given set of inputs.

If you want to build a TTL cache, I would recommend looking at [wrap()](https://lodash.com/docs#wrap). Use this to wrap your functions with a generic function that does the caching and TTL checks.

Answer (score 4):

As an example Adam's answer to use the `_.wrap` method you can do:

```
var myExpensiveFunction = _.wrap(myExpensiveFunction, function(originalFunction, param1) {
  if (/* data is in cache and TTL not expired */){
      // return cachedValue
  } else {
      // run originalFunction(param1) and save cachedValue
      // return cachedValue;
  }
});
```

If your expensive function returns a promise, don't forget to return a resolved promise instead of cachedValue directly if cache exists